# How to fix my program so that my functions can work?

Tags: c++, function, void

For HW (intro to C++) I had to modify a program that I wrote previously, I will be including that code here. Seeing the output of it will make things much more clearer:

```
//Program to compute and display the average and appropriate letter grade of   3 test scores 
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char grade;
    double Test_1,Test_2,Test_3,Avg,ClassAvg1,ClassAvg2,ClassAvg3;
    int sumTest_1,sumTest_2,sumTest_3;
    int n;
    sumTest_1=sumTest_2=sumTest_3=0;
    const int totalSum=5.0;
    for(n=1;n<=5;n++) {
        do {
            cout<<"What are the three test scores for student #"<<n;
            cin>>Test_1>>Test_2>>Test_3;
            if(Test_1<1||Test_1>100||Test_2<1||Test_2>100||Test_3<1||Test_3>100)
            cout<<"You entered an invalid score - please try again"<<endl;
        }

        while(Test_1<1||Test_1>100||Test_2<1||Test_2>100||Test_3<1||Test_3>100);
        Avg=((Test_1+Test_2+Test_3)/3.0);

        if(Avg<65) {
            grade= 'F';
        }
        else if(Avg<70)
        {
            grade= 'D';
        }
        else if(Avg<80)
        {
            grade= 'C';
        }
        else if(Avg<90)
        {
            grade= 'B';
        }
        else
        {
            grade='A';
        }
        cout<<setprecision (0)<<fixed;
        cout<<"Your test average is "<<Avg<<" and your grade is "        <<grade<<endl;
        sumTest_1=sumTest_1+Test_1;
        sumTest_2=sumTest_2+Test_2;
        sumTest_3=sumTest_3+Test_3;
        ClassAvg1=sumTest_1/5.0;
        ClassAvg2=sumTest_2/5.0;
        ClassAvg3=sumTest_3/5.0;
    }
    cout<<"The class average for test #1 is: "<<ClassAvg1<<endl;
    cout<<"The class average for test #2 is: "<<ClassAvg2<<endl;
    cout<<"The class average for test #3 is: "<<ClassAvg3<<endl; 
}
```

For hw, I have to modify the program above by including two functions, **ComputeAvg** which will be called to compute and return the student's average and **LetterGrade**, to compute and return the letter grade. This is so that instead of using one main program, I now use these 2 functions. I have written this code so far, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right and it will be great if someone can explain things out for me since I'm still  not very comfortable writing functions:

```
//Program to compute and display the average and appropriate letter grade of        3 test scores
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void ComputeAvg(int Test_1, int Test_2, int Test_3)
{
    double Avg;
    double ComputeAvg(int Test_1,int Test_2,int Test_3);
    {
        Avg=ComputeAvg(Test_1,Test_2,Test_3);
        return(Test_1+Test_2+Test_3)/3.0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int Test_1,Test_2,Test_3,n;
    double Avg;
    for(n=1;n<=5;n++)
    {
        do
        {
            cout<<"What are the three test scores for student #"<<n;

            cin>>Test_1>>Test_2>>Test_3;

            if(Test_1<1||Test_1>100||Test_2<1||Test_2>100||Test_3<1||Test_3>100)

            cout<<"You entered an invalid score - please try again"<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"Your test average is:"<<Avg<<endl;
        ComputeAvg(Test_1,Test_2,Test_3);

    }
}



#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

void LetterGrade(int Test_1, int Test_2, int Test_3)
{
    double Avg;
    double LetterGrade(int Test_1,int Test_2,int Test_3);
    {
        Grade=LetterGrade(Test_1,Test_2,Test_3);
```

Comment: What were the compiler error and warning message?  Please edit your post and not put in comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
void ComputeAvg(int Test_1, int Test_2, int Test_3)
{
  double Avg;
  double ComputeAvg(int Test_1,int Test_2,int Test_3);
  {
    Avg=ComputeAvg(Test_1,Test_2,Test_3);
    return(Test_1+Test_2+Test_3)/3.0;
  }
}
```

The above code doesn't look correct, especially using a nested function or recursion.

Something tells me you want a simplified version:

```
double Compute_Average(int test_1, int test_2, int test_3)
{
  return (  static_cast<double>(test_1)
          + static_cast<double>(test_2)
          + static_cast<double>(test_3))
          / 3.0;
}
```

Since the function is returning a value, in your `main` function you want to store the result in a variable:

```
double Avg = Compute_Average(Test_1, Test_2, Test_3);
cout << "Test average is: " << Avg << "\n";
```

Comment: My professor gave us that portion of the code to write out our program though, he wants us to use nested functions with the void, even though I do prefer writing a much more simpler code but he doesn't want that.

Comment: The problem is that the "nested" function returns a value, but the outer function doesn't return anything.  The parameters are not passed by reference and they are not global.  Soooo, no information comes out of the function.  It's worthless.'

Comment: Quit your class and take a different course.  I've never had to use a nested function.  You also need to talk with the instructor and ask if your implementation of the function meets the requirement.